# page is not refreshing implicitly in jquery ajax while deleting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this two ajax jquery function to add ,display and delete data from table the table ,delete works fine ut while adding the data gets saved but only gets displayed when i refresh ,how do i fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    (function ($) {z
        $.fn.serializeFormJSON = function () {

            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function () {
                if (o[this.name]) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
            return o;
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serializeFormJSON();
        console.log(data);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json",

         url: "createajaxuser",
         data:JSON.stringify(data),
         dataType: "json",

         success: function(result) {
            a    
         }
     });
    });


    $.ajax({
        url: 'listusersjson',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            var trHTML = '';
            var count =0;
            $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                console.debug("i is"+i);

                var success="success";
                var danger="danger";
                var info="info";

                 var color ;
                 if(count==0)
                     {
                     color =success;
                     count++;
                     }else if(count==1){
                         color =danger;
                         count++;
                     }else{
                         color =info;
                         count=0;

                     }
                trHTML += '<tr class="'+color+'" ><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>' + item.id + '</td><td>' + item.password +  '</td><td>' + item.email+
                    '</td><td>' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="' + item.id + '" >Delete</button>'
                '</td></tr>';
            });
            $('#delTable').append(trHTML);
            $('button').click(function() {
               var val = $(this).attr("id");
               console.debug("saurabh userid", val);
               var rowElement = $(this).parent().parent();
               $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",

                url: "ajaxuserr/"+val,
                success: function(result) {
                    rowElement.find('td').fadeOut('3000',
                        function() {
                            rowElement.remove();
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        });
        }
    });

});

</script>


</head>
<body>

    <form action="#" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label> <input type="text" name="name"
                id="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email</label> <input type="text" name="email"
                id="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label> <input type="password"
                name="password" id="password" />
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="delTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="100">Name</th>
                    <th width="100">ID</th>
                    <th width="100">Password</th>
                    <th width="100">Email</th>
                    <th width="100">Delete</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>


            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: your form submit must add data to the table right?? The problem is you are submitting the data and in the ajax success method you are not doing anything to update the table. Either update the table by adding new row into it or call your Ajax method which displays the table again.

Comment: how do i call ajax metod wch displays table again

Comment: is  your tbody empty initially in the page and you are building the tbody using jquery?

Comment: it depends on the data in db

Comment: Ok, now In your ajax call where you call `listusersjson` you are actually getting array of objects and you are looping through each object and creating a row. Finillay you are appending it to the table. Now you can do two things, 1) when you save the new record make the server return only one object (the new record created), you can then add it into table in similar way, 2) put the ajax call where you do `listusersjson` into a function. And just call this function when ever there is a new reord inserted.(make sure you remove previous tbody and then call the function )

Comment: Let me know if you want me to post a answer describing the same as explained above.

Comment: just tell me how do i call the ajax method which displays lists of users from success function

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer because you are getting confused when I am tring to explain in comments,

So initially put your ajax call that builds the table tbody into a new Function like below.

```
  function GetListOfUsers(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'listusersjson',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            var trHTML = '';
            var count =0;
            $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                console.debug("i is"+i);

                var success="success";
                var danger="danger";
                var info="info";

                 var color ;
                 if(count==0)
                     {
                     color =success;
                     count++;
                     }else if(count==1){
                         color =danger;
                         count++;
                     }else{
                         color =info;
                         count=0;

                     }
                trHTML += '<tr class="'+color+'" ><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>' + item.id + '</td><td>' + item.password +  '</td><td>' + item.email+
                    '</td><td>' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="' + item.id + '" >Delete</button>'
                '</td></tr>';
            });
            $('#delTable tbody').append(trHTML); //Note I am trying to append into tbody you were directly appending to table without tbody
            $('button').click(function() {
               var val = $(this).attr("id");
               console.debug("saurabh userid", val);
               var rowElement = $(this).parent().parent();
               $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",

                url: "ajaxuserr/"+val,
                success: function(result) {
                    rowElement.find('td').fadeOut('3000',
                        function() {
                            rowElement.remove();
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        });
        }
    });

});

}
```

And then you can call this method in the success method of the form submit ajax call. like below

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeFormJSON();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json",

     url: "createajaxuser",
     data:JSON.stringify(data),
     dataType: "json",

     success: function(result) {
         $('#delTable tbody').html(''); //empty the tbody
        GetListOfUsers();   // call this function so that it rebuilds the tbody
     }
 });
});
```

Also since now we moved the ajax call that builds the tbody into a new function, you have to call this once in your initial script load. So that it builds up the tbody. So you can place this line of code after your form submit event handler
`GetListOfUsers();`

Comment: i got what u r sying,but success function is not executing at all even though its returning status 201

Comment: OK what is your server side code trying to return after the data is being inserted into the DB?

Comment: i added this error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.debug("saurabh error");
   // console.log("Error " + jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders() + " " + errorThrown);
   },

Comment: So what does the error say? you can see it in console window of the browser

Comment: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input(…)

Comment: recheck you server side code,  by the way what language have you used in server side